# React redux - store isn't loaded but no errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am following the [code example](https://github.com/MoonHighway/learning-react/tree/master/chapter-11/color-organizer) from Learning React book. It is about react redux and react router used for single page app.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/andrii-p/car-saver) to my project where I mimic the example above. You can clone it and run with `npm install` and `npm run dev`. (Note: project also has back end code but it is irrelevant. Question is only about front end part where I use static data file.)

I can successfully run the example locally, but when I run my project I see my store being empty when it comes to load ui components. I don't get any compile or console errors, and I see other parts of the app working fine. I spent lots of time debugging store creation code but I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Please help to find the reason.

Here are my findings:

There are two url available in my project: `/` and `/cars`. The `/cars` url reads data file directly and it does output all the data correctly.

The root url suppose to do the same by utilizing redux store. However the data array used by ui component comes empty. I guess there is something wrong with the code for store creation (below), although I precisely mimicked the code example. There is literally only one change that I made which is `carsReducer`, and I coded it exactly as other reducers in the example.

I also noticed that `localStorage` isn't being populated in the console, but it doesn't give much clue.

```
src/main/resources/static/js/store/index.js

const storeFactory = (initialState=stateData) =>
    applyMiddleware(logger, saver)(createStore)(
        combineReducers({carsReducer}),
        (localStorage['redux-store']) ?
            JSON.parse(localStorage['redux-store']) :
            initialState
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend you some fixes:

**js/index.js** — Main provider file

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './components/App'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import store from './store'

window.React = React
window.store = store

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
            <App />
        </HashRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
)
```

**js/store/index.js** — Store file

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import {carsReducer} from './reducers'
import stateData from '../../data/cars.json'

let console = window.console

const logger = store => next => action => {
    let result
    console.groupCollapsed("dispatching", action.type)
    console.log('prev state', store.getState())
    console.log('action', action)
    result = next(action)
    console.log('next state', store.getState())
    console.groupEnd()
    return result
}

const saver = store => next => action => {
    let result = next(action)
    localStorage['redux-store'] = JSON.stringify(store.getState())
    return result
}

const initialState = localStorage['redux-store'] || stateData

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({...carsReducer}),
    stateData,
    applyMiddleware(logger, saver)
)

export default store
```

**CarsTable.js** — And some fixes to cars list JSX structure

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import CarRow from './CarRow'

const CarsTable = ({cars = []}) =>
    <div>
        {(cars.length === 0) ?
            <p>Cars list is empty.</p> :
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ad name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Odometer</th>
                    <th>Condition</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {
                    cars.map((car, i) =>
                        <CarRow key={i} car={car} />
                    )
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    </div>

CarsTable.propTypes = {
    cars: PropTypes.array
}

export default CarsTable
```

Comment: Many thanks for help! It did fix the issue, but could you please help me understand the cause? I really want to get to the bottom of it.

The actual change from your post that fixed my current code is to use spread operator in the `combineReducers({...carsReducer})` (all other tips are helpful too).  However, I can't wrap around my head why it works fine in the example that I followed and didn't work in my case. Do you have any ideas by any chance?

Comment: @Kurt glad to help you! Of course, you can do like `combineReducers({ carsReducer })`. To make it work you need to export your `carsReducer` in other way. Take a look & try: https://gist.github.com/armenavetisyan/1f866d84b3bd5149ad0b617fe54b7f4f

Comment: Your example is working fine. So the only thing you changed is the way the function is being exported - you changed `export const carsReducer` to `const carsReducer` + `export default carsReducer`. I don't understand why this change makes my original example to work. Aren't these two export approaches do the same thing? Or is there some subtle difference that I'm not getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try having a constructor and initialize your `Store` on `/car-saver/src/main/resources/static/js/index.js`

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.store = configureStore();
}
```

and pass it to your `<Provider store={this.store}>`

Comment: What did you mean with configureStore() method? Are you referring to storeFactory() that I'm using in my project or is it something completely different?

Comment: your js/store/index.js — Store file

Comment: ahh I see you did not use createStore